# PHPMailer not working: Message could not be sent

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, contact-form

I am trying to create a contact form on my website using PHPMailer. I am having some trouble setting it up. I am trying to use G-mail as my smtp host. I was wondering if anyone can help troubleshoot this?

This is my mailer code:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();   
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication      
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail        
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 467;  

$mail->Username = "validmail@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "workingpassword"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "validmail@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
$mail->AddAddress("josh@example.net", "Josh Adams");
$mail->AddAddress("ellen@example.com");                  // name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@example.com", "Information");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters


// $mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
   // $mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

The error message:

```
Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: The following From address failed: validmail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Hard to tell why it's not working. Have you tried `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;`

Comment: Yes I have. This is the error it displayed : SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (12640394)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at and tried the info from this Q?

[PHPMailer: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

In particular, does this provide any additional info?

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, dubugging definitely helped some. This is the error it the smtp debug code added to the screen: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (12640394)

Comment: Per the other Q, it sounds like you have to enable   

    extension=php_openssl.dll.

Answer (score 3):

smtp.gmail.com requires that you use SSL and port 587 or 465.

See their configuration page: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: Also, look at similar SO Question/Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525855/problem-with-using-phpmailer-for-smtp

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried this, it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running PHP on Windows? Then this might help:

http://www.devcha.com/2010/01/php-fsockopen-unable-to-connect-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error and the problem was that i was trying to sent email from "boy333@in**" account pretending as "girl333@in**". I just changed

```
$mail->From = 'girl333@in**'
```

to username i was actually connecting. So I changed to:

```
$mail->From = 'boy333@in**'
```

The idea is that these two fields is with the same usernames.

```
$mail->Username   = "boy333";
$mail->From = 'boy333@in**';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded


    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $messageField = $_POST['message'];
    $phoneField = $_POST['contactno'];
    $cityField = $_POST['city'];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

$body .= $nameField;

try {
     //$mail->Host       = "mail.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
      $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
      $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
      $mail->Port       = 465;   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
      $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
      $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
      $mail->Username   = "xxxxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
      $mail->Password   = "********";            // GMAIL password
      $mail->AddAddress('sendto@gmail.com', 'abc');
      $mail->SetFrom('xxxxxx@gmail.com', 'def');
      $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
      $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
      $mail->MsgHTML($body);
      $mail->Send();
      echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
      header("location: ../test.html");
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}

?>
```

Go to google settings and enable 'less secure' applications. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ping smtp.gmail.com
```

For some reason, google redirects SMTP requests to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com

```
PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (74.125.133.108): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.133.108: icmp_seq=0 ttl=43 time=72.636 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.133.108: icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=68.841 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.133.108: icmp_seq=2 ttl=43 time=68.500 ms
```

So you should put the final destination in your config, as PHPMailer does not follow redirections. Also you may try to send emails without SMTPSecure by keeping that field blank.

```
$mail->Host = 'gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
$mail->Username = 'email';   
$mail->Password = 'password';    
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';   
$mail->Port = 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your email in gsuite check two steps:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Php Mail Settings;
PHPMailer version 5.2.22
Check class.phpmailer.php,

```
  var $Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  var $Port = 465;
  var $Helo ='domain.net';
  public $SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  public $SMTPAutoTLS = true;
  public $SMTPAuth = true;
  public $SMTPOptions = array();
  public $Username = 'gmail-username';//or domain credentials on google mail
  public $Password = 'gmail-password';
  public $Timeout = 10;
  public $SMTPDebug = true;
```

mail send php

```
<?php
require('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require('PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');

$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";    
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet="SET NAMES UTF8";
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->CharSet="utf8";
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->port       = 465;
$mail->smtpauth   = true;
$mail->smtpsecure = 'ssl';
$mail->username   = "gmail-username"; //or domain credentials on google mail
$mail->password   = "gmail-password";
$mail->SetFrom('from-email', 'from-name');
$mail->AddAddress('to-address', 'to-address');
$mail->Body = 'your-text'; //emailbody
if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
            mysql_close();
        echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo."');</script>";
        } 
        else 
        {
        mysql_close();
        echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";
        }

?>
```

This is work for me. Hope it helps.