# PHPMailer is not working

Tags: php, phpmailer, hotmail

Good day!

I downloaded PHPMailer class from the Google code page: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/. I'm running this with:

```
PHP 5.2.14 (cli) (built: Jul 27 2010 10:49:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

On a Windows 7 machine and I'm using the following test code:

```
require("PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();  

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.live.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "some_email@hotmail.nl";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From     = "some_email@hotmail.nl";
$mail->AddAddress("some_other_email@hotmail.nl");  

$mail->Subject  = "Subject";
$mail->Body     = "Hi!";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
```

I'm also sure that the password and the user name are correct, but I get the following error:

```
Message was not sent.Mailer error: The following From address failed: some_email@hotmail.nl
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPMailer not working: Message could not be sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981968/phpmailer-not-working-message-could-not-be-sent)

Comment: I have enabled openssl. extension=php_openssl.dll...

Comment: Is this the only address you can't send email to, or it fails with each email you tried?

Comment: make sure you can telnet to that port from server like "telnet smtp.live.com 587" or something similar.

Comment: Jori, have you tried also to change ssl to tls protocol?

Comment: Will try that! Also, 587 is the correct port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use live.com, so I tested your script with my gmail account and it worked well. You can make sure, you have the [correct Username and Password set for your live.com account](http://email.about.com/od/accessinghotmail/f/Windows_Live_Hotmail_SMTP_Settings.htm). Or you can try to set **$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';**   This works well with gmail:

```php
require("PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "yourNickname@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourPassword";
$mail->From     = "some_email@hotmail.nl";
$mail->AddAddress("receiver@server.ext");
$mail->Subject  = "Subject";
$mail->Body     = "Hi!";
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Comment: Adding $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; did the job!