# SMTP PHPMailer doesn't work

Tags: php, smtp

I tried to use google as SMTP server like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525855/problem-with-using-phpmailer-for-smtp) but it cannot send mail. How to fix it? It seems that there is firewall which blocks my script.

```
<?php
    require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465; // SMTP Port
    $mail->Username   = "emerald.hieu.test@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "xxx";        // SMTP account password

    $mail->SetFrom('emerald.hieu.test@gmail.com', 'Hieutot'); // FROM
    $mail->AddReplyTo('emerald.hieu.test@gmail.com', 'Hieutot'); // Reply TO

    $mail->AddAddress('nguyen.hieu@xxx.vn', 'HieuND2'); // recipient email

    $mail->Subject    = "First SMTP Message"; // email subject
    $mail->Body       = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through Google SMTP using PHPMailer.";

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
```

This is my log:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): timed-out (10 seconds) 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "" 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedThe following From address failed: emerald.hieu.test@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected Message was not sent.Mailer error: The following From address failed: emerald.hieu.test@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using:

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

in place of:

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```